# Using PIL to fill empty image space with nearby colors (aka inpainting)

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, python-imaging-library

I create an image with PIL:

[image: example image]

I need to fill in the empty space (depicted as black). I could easily fill it with a static color, but what I'd like to do is fill the pixels in with nearby colors. For example, the first pixel after the border might be a Gaussian blur of the filled-in pixels. Or perhaps a push-pull type algorithm described in [The Lumigraph, Gortler, et al.](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=68168).

I need something that is not too slow because I have to run this on many images. I have access to other libraries, like numpy, and you can assume that I know the borders or a mask of the outside region or inside region. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by belisarius, [opencv's inpaint](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-inpaint) method is perfect for this. Here's some python code that uses opencv to achieve what I wanted:

```
import Image, ImageDraw, cv

im = Image.open("u7XVL.png")
pix = im.load()

#create a mask of the background colors
# this is slow, but easy for example purposes
mask = Image.new('L', im.size)
maskdraw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
for x in range(im.size[0]):
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        if pix[(x,y)] == (0,0,0):
            maskdraw.point((x,y), 255)

#convert image and mask to opencv format
cv_im = cv.CreateImageHeader(im.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
cv.SetData(cv_im, im.tostring())
cv_mask = cv.CreateImageHeader(mask.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
cv.SetData(cv_mask, mask.tostring())

#do the inpainting
cv_painted_im = cv.CloneImage(cv_im)
cv.Inpaint(cv_im, cv_mask, cv_painted_im, 3, cv.CV_INPAINT_NS)

#convert back to PIL
painted_im = Image.fromstring("RGB", cv.GetSize(cv_painted_im), cv_painted_im.tostring())
painted_im.show()
```

And the resulting image:

[image: painted image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A method with nice results is the [**Navier-Stokes Image Restoration**.](http://www.dtic.upf.edu/~mbertalmio/final-cvpr.pdf) I know OpenCV has it, don't know about PIL.

Your example:

[image]  [image]

I did it with Mathematica.

**Edit**

As per your reuquest, the code is:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEPqc.png"];
Inpaint[i, ColorNegate@Binarize@i, Method -> "NavierStokes"]
```

The  ColorNegate@ ...  part creates the replacement mask.
The filling is done with just the `Inpaint[]` command.

Comment: Awesome. I've put some sample python code that converts from PIL to opencv and does the painting in my question. Accepted your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @jterrace Glad to help! I voted up your question too, because it is a very good example of how useful SO can be.

Comment: any idea why inpaint always misses x=0 and y=0 (the top row and left column) of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're deploying this application, another option might be to use the Gimp's [python interface](http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html) to do the image manipulation.

The doc page I linked to is oriented more towards writing GIMP plugins in python, rather than interacting with a background gimp instance from a python app, but I'm pretty sure that's also possible (it's been a while since I played with the gimp/python interface, I'm a little hazy).

Comment: Does it have a routine to do something like this?

Comment: Sadly, I'm not sure if it has a plugin that matches what you want... I mainly posted it as an option you might not be aware of, since it has have some more powerful tools to build from: masks, gaussian blur filters, and a pythonic interface to the lowlevel pixel region objects. Now that I think about it more, it might be bloated overkill for your purposes, especially if you have to process a lot of files. Though one algorithm that might make it worth it is the [resynthesizer](http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/resynthesizer) plugin for the Gimp, which is a "content aware fill" algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

You can also create the mask with the function `CreateImage()`, for instance:

```
inpaint_mask = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im), 8, 1)
```