# Matrix completion in Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mathematical-optimization

Say I have a matrix:

```
> import numpy as nap
> a = np.random.random((5,5))

array([[ 0.28164485,  0.76200749,  0.59324211,  0.15201506,  0.74084168],
       [ 0.83572213,  0.63735993,  0.28039542,  0.19191284,  0.48419414],
       [ 0.99967476,  0.8029097 ,  0.53140614,  0.24026153,  0.94805153],
       [ 0.92478   ,  0.43488547,  0.76320656,  0.39969956,  0.46490674],
       [ 0.83315135,  0.94781119,  0.80455425,  0.46291229,  0.70498372]])
```

And that I punch some holes in it with `np.NaN`, e.g.:

```
> a[(1,4,0,3),(2,4,2,0)] = np.NaN; 

array([[ 0.80327707,  0.87722234,         nan,  0.94463778,  0.78089194],
       [ 0.90584284,  0.18348667,         nan,  0.82401826,  0.42947815],
       [ 0.05913957,  0.15512961,  0.08328608,  0.97636309,  0.84573433],
       [        nan,  0.30120861,  0.46829231,  0.52358888,  0.89510461],
       [ 0.19877877,  0.99423591,  0.17236892,  0.88059185,        nan ]])
```

I would like to fill-in the `nan` entries using information from the rest of entries of the matrix. An example would be using the **average** value of the column where the `nan` entries occur.

More generally, are there any libraries in Python for [matrix completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_completion) ? (e.g. something along the lines of [Candes & Recht's convex optimization method](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/%7Ecandes/papers/MatrixCompletion.pdf)).

#### Background:

This problem appears often in machine learning. For example when working with **missing features** in classification/regression or in [**collaborative filtering**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) (e.g. see the Netflix Problem on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix_Prize) and [here](http://www.cs.uic.edu/%7Eliub/KDD-cup-2007/proceedings.html))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you install the latest scikit-learn, version 0.14a1, you can use its shiny new `Imputer` class:

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
>>> imp = Imputer(strategy="mean")
>>> a = np.random.random((5,5))
>>> a[(1,4,0,3),(2,4,2,0)] = np.nan
>>> a
array([[ 0.77473361,  0.62987193,         nan,  0.11367791,  0.17633671],
       [ 0.68555944,  0.54680378,         nan,  0.64186838,  0.15563309],
       [ 0.37784422,  0.59678177,  0.08103329,  0.60760487,  0.65288022],
       [        nan,  0.54097945,  0.30680838,  0.82303869,  0.22784574],
       [ 0.21223024,  0.06426663,  0.34254093,  0.22115931,         nan]])
>>> a = imp.fit_transform(a)
>>> a
array([[ 0.77473361,  0.62987193,  0.24346087,  0.11367791,  0.17633671],
       [ 0.68555944,  0.54680378,  0.24346087,  0.64186838,  0.15563309],
       [ 0.37784422,  0.59678177,  0.08103329,  0.60760487,  0.65288022],
       [ 0.51259188,  0.54097945,  0.30680838,  0.82303869,  0.22784574],
       [ 0.21223024,  0.06426663,  0.34254093,  0.22115931,  0.30317394]])
```

After this, you can use `imp.transform` to do the same transformation to other data, using the mean that `imp` learned from `a`. Imputers tie into scikit-learn `Pipeline` objects so you can use them in classification or regression pipelines.

If you want to wait for a stable release, then 0.14 should be out next week.

Full disclosure: I'm a scikit-learn core developer

Comment: But it fails to rows with all unknown values. Furthermore, is there a more advanced matrix completion method? For Imputer, it infers values based only on median, mean or frequent values.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with pure numpy, but its nastier.

```
from scipy.stats import nanmean
>>> a
array([[ 0.70309466,  0.53785006,         nan,  0.49590115,  0.23521493],
       [ 0.29067786,  0.48236186,         nan,  0.93220001,  0.76261019],
       [ 0.66243065,  0.07731947,  0.38887545,  0.56450533,  0.58647126],
       [        nan,  0.7870873 ,  0.60010096,  0.88778259,  0.09097726],
       [ 0.02750389,  0.72328898,  0.69820328,  0.02435883,         nan]])


>>> mean=nanmean(a,axis=0)
>>> mean
array([ 0.42092677,  0.52158153,  0.56239323,  0.58094958,  0.41881841])
>>> index=np.where(np.isnan(a))

>>> a[index]=np.take(mean,index[1])
>>> a
array([[ 0.70309466,  0.53785006,  0.56239323,  0.49590115,  0.23521493],
       [ 0.29067786,  0.48236186,  0.56239323,  0.93220001,  0.76261019],
       [ 0.66243065,  0.07731947,  0.38887545,  0.56450533,  0.58647126],
       [ 0.42092677,  0.7870873 ,  0.60010096,  0.88778259,  0.09097726],
       [ 0.02750389,  0.72328898,  0.69820328,  0.02435883,  0.41881841]])
```

Running some timings:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import nanmean

a = np.random.random((10000,10000))
col=np.random.randint(0,10000,500)
row=np.random.randint(0,10000,500)
a[(col,row)]=np.nan
a1=np.copy(a)


%timeit mean=nanmean(a,axis=0);index=np.where(np.isnan(a));a[index]=np.take(mean,index[1])
1 loops, best of 3: 1.84 s per loop

%timeit DF=pd.DataFrame(a1);col_means = DF.apply(np.mean, 0);DF.fillna(value=col_means)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.81 s per loop

#Surprisingly, issue could be apply looping over the zero axis.
DF=pd.DataFrame(a2)
%timeit col_means = DF.apply(np.mean, 0);DF.fillna(value=col_means)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.57 s per loop
```

I do not believe numpy has array completion routines built in; however, pandas does. View the help topic [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html).

Answer (score 5):

The exact method you desire (Candes and Recht, 2008) is available for Python in the `fancyimpute` library, located here ([link](https://github.com/iskandr/fancyimpute)).

```
from fancyimpute import NuclearNormMinimization

# X is the complete data matrix
# X_incomplete has the same values as X except a subset have been replace with NaN

X_filled_nnm = NuclearNormMinimization().complete(X_incomplete)
```

I've seen good results from it. Thankfully, they changed the autodiff and SGD backend from `downhill`, which uses `Theano` under the hood, to `keras` over the past year. The algorithm is available in this library too ([link](https://github.com/tonyduan/matrix-completion)). SciKit-Learn's `Imputer()` does not include this algorithm. It's not in the documentation, but you can install `fancyimpute` with `pip`:

```
pip install fancyimpute
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this quite simply with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.DataFrame(a)
col_means = DF.apply(np.mean, 0)
DF.fillna(value=col_means)
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, the documentation talks about `bfill`, `backfill`, `pad` and `ffill`. Where can I read more about these methods? (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: `bfill` is shorthand for `backfill` and `ffill` is "shorthand" for `pad`. I don't think there is much in the way of documentation but the code is [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/fcaf9a666114cac67093823e6752b91391f84e1a/pandas/core/common.py)

Comment: In addition you should read up on pandas missing data help, [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html).

Answer (score 2):

Similar questions have been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478347/how-do-i-fill-holes-in-an-image) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551286/filling-gaps-in-a-numpy-array) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098410/using-pil-to-fill-empty-image-space-with-nearby-colors-aka-inpainting). What you need is a special case of [inpaiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting). Unfortunately, neither numpy or scipy have builtin routines for this. However, OpenCV has a function [`inpaint()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#inpaint), but it only works on 8-bit images.

[OpenPIV](http://www.openpiv.net/openpiv-python/src/generated/openpiv.lib.replace_nans.html) has a `replace_nans` function that you can use for your purposes. ([See here](https://github.com/gasagna/openpiv-python/blob/master/openpiv/src/lib.pyx) for Cython version that you can repackage if you don't want to install the whole library.) It is more flexible than a pure mean or propagation of older values as suggested in other answers (e.g., you can defined different weighting functions, kernel sizes, etc.).

Using the examples from @Ophion, I compared the `replace_nans` with the `nanmean` and Pandas solutions:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import nanmean

a = np.random.random((10000,10000))
col=np.random.randint(0,10000,500)
row=np.random.randint(0,10000,500)
a[(col,row)]=np.nan
a1=np.copy(a)

%timeit new_array = replace_nans(a1, 10, 0.5, 1.)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.57 s per loop

%timeit mean=nanmean(a,axis=0);index=np.where(np.isnan(a));a[index]=np.take(mean,index[1])
1 loops, best of 3: 2.23 s per loop

%timeit DF=pd.DataFrame(a1);col_means = DF.apply(np.mean, 0);DF.fillna(value=col_means)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.23 s per loop
```

The `replace_nans` solution is arguably better and faster.

Comment: Unless I am missing something `replace_nans` fills `nans` with a weighted average and will not be equivalent to replacing the `nans` with the average of the column. With 4 if statements inside 4 loops im not sure how much faster it will be if your array contains many nans. I would be very curious of the timings if you changed the number of nans to 5000 from 500.

Comment: @Opion: you are right, it is not replacing the nans with the average of the column. But that was the point: the column average is not the best replacement. For curiosity I just re-ran the timings using `np.random.randint(0,10000,5000)` for `col` and `row`. `replace_nans` now took 1.55 s, and `nanmean` took 2.15 s. So, pretty similar...

Comment: Are you sure it has replace all `nans` in 10 iterations? I do apologize for being skeptical- the code just doesn't appear to be an efficient way of doing this at first glance.

Comment: It does seem to have replaced all NaNs in 10 iterations. Just try for yourself. The point here is not finding the code that is faster at replacing the largest number of NaNs, but finding the best estimate for the missing values. Inpainting is not designed for images with a large proportion of NaNs.