# filling gaps on an image using numpy and scipy

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

The image (test.tif) is attached.
The np.nan values are the whitest region.
How to fill those whitest region  using some gap filling algorithms that uses values from the neighbours?

> [image]

```
import scipy.ndimage

data = ndimage.imread('test.tif')
```

Comment: Look at the scipy interpolate library to find a function fitting your needs. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think *viena's* question is more related to an [inpainting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting) problem.

Here are some ideas:

- In order to fill the gaps in B/W images you can use some *filling* algorithm like [scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes.html#scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes). But you have a gray level image, so you can't use it.
- I suppose that you don't want to use a complex inpainting algorithm. My first suggestion is: Don't try to use Nearest gray value (you don't know the real value of the NaN pixels). Using the NEarest value will generate a dirty algorithm. Instead, I would suggest you to **fill the gaps with some other value** (e.g. the mean of the row). You can do it without coding by using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html):

[Source:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18001880/3153644)

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
>>> imp = Imputer(strategy="mean")
>>> a = np.random.random((5,5))
>>> a[(1,4,0,3),(2,4,2,0)] = np.nan
>>> a
array([[ 0.77473361,  0.62987193,         nan,  0.11367791,  0.17633671],
   [ 0.68555944,  0.54680378,         nan,  0.64186838,  0.15563309],
   [ 0.37784422,  0.59678177,  0.08103329,  0.60760487,  0.65288022],
   [        nan,  0.54097945,  0.30680838,  0.82303869,  0.22784574],
   [ 0.21223024,  0.06426663,  0.34254093,  0.22115931,         nan]])
>>> a = imp.fit_transform(a)
>>> a
array([[ 0.77473361,  0.62987193,  0.24346087,  0.11367791,  0.17633671],
   [ 0.68555944,  0.54680378,  0.24346087,  0.64186838,  0.15563309],
   [ 0.37784422,  0.59678177,  0.08103329,  0.60760487,  0.65288022],
   [ 0.51259188,  0.54097945,  0.30680838,  0.82303869,  0.22784574],
   [ 0.21223024,  0.06426663,  0.34254093,  0.22115931,  0.30317394]])
```

- The **dirty solution** that uses the Nearest values can be this:
  1) Find the perimeter points of the NaN regions
  2) Compute *all* the distances between the NaN points and the perimeter
  3) Replace the NaNs with the nearest's point gray value

Comment: For those looking for `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer`: the functionalities have moved under `sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer`, see docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html#sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer). The nearest neighbour ("dirty solution") has also been implemented in `sklearn.impute.KNNImputer`, the docs of which can be found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html#sklearn.impute.KNNImputer).

Answer (score 22):

As others have suggested, scipy.interpolate can be used.  However, it requires fairly extensive index manipulation to get this to work.

Complete example:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy
import scipy.ndimage
import scipy.interpolate
import pdb

data = scipy.ndimage.imread('data.png')

# a boolean array of (width, height) which False where there are missing values and True where there are valid (non-missing) values
mask = ~( (data[:,:,0] == 255) & (data[:,:,1] == 255) & (data[:,:,2] == 255) )

# array of (number of points, 2) containing the x,y coordinates of the valid values only
xx, yy = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.arange(data.shape[1]), numpy.arange(data.shape[0]))
xym = numpy.vstack( (numpy.ravel(xx[mask]), numpy.ravel(yy[mask])) ).T

# the valid values in the first, second, third color channel,  as 1D arrays (in the same order as their coordinates in xym)
data0 = numpy.ravel( data[:,:,0][mask] )
data1 = numpy.ravel( data[:,:,1][mask] )
data2 = numpy.ravel( data[:,:,2][mask] )

# three separate interpolators for the separate color channels
interp0 = scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator( xym, data0 )
interp1 = scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator( xym, data1 )
interp2 = scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator( xym, data2 )

# interpolate the whole image, one color channel at a time    
result0 = interp0(numpy.ravel(xx), numpy.ravel(yy)).reshape( xx.shape )
result1 = interp1(numpy.ravel(xx), numpy.ravel(yy)).reshape( xx.shape )
result2 = interp2(numpy.ravel(xx), numpy.ravel(yy)).reshape( xx.shape )

# combine them into an output image
result = numpy.dstack( (result0, result1, result2) )

imshow(result)
show()
```

Output:

[image]

This passes to the interpolator all values we have, not just the ones next to the missing values (which may be somewhat inefficient).  It also interpolates *every* point in the output, not just the missing values (which is extremely inefficient).  A better way is to interpolate just the missing values, and then patch them into the original image.  This is just a quick working example to get started :)

Answer (score 8):

If you want values from the nearest neighbors, you could use the [NearestNDInterpolator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator) from scipy.interpolate. There are also [other interpolators](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#id1) as well you can consider.

You can locate the X,Y index values for the NaN values with:

```
import numpy as np

nan_locs = np.where(np.isnan(data))
```

There are some other options for the interpolation as well. One option is to replace NaN values with the results of a [median filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) (but your areas are kind of large for this). Another option might be [grayscale dilation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_dilation.html#scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_dilation). The correct interpolation depends on your end domain.

If you haven't used a SciPy ND interpolator before, you'll need to provide X, Y, and value data to fit the interpolator to then X and Y data for values to interpolate at. You can do this using the where example above as a template.

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV has some image in-painting algorithms that you could use. You just need to provide a binary mask which indicates which pixels should be in-painted.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

data = ndimage.imread("test.tif")
mask = np.isnan(data)
inpainted_img = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, inpaintRadius=3, flags=cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```